# Haskell . Why does my parser fail

Tags: parsing, haskell, trifecta

As as exercise of the Haskell Book written by bitemyapp  I need to make a parser which can parse the given log. 
So I made this : https://gist.github.com/RoelofWobben/79058b1a6a5c24f08a495045c7a685f9

but when I test it with :  ` parseString parseMultipleDays myLog I see this error message :

```
Failure (ErrInfo {_errDoc = (interactive):3:1: error: expected: new-line
# 2025-02-05
^            , _errDeltas = [Lines 2 0 20 0]})
```

anyone who can give me a hint where the bug is. When needed I can make a repo of the code I have with some tests.

I use trifecta because that one is explained in the chapter

Answer (score 1):

```
string "--" *> manyTill anyChar newline *> newline
```

`manyTill` already consumes the terminator, so the above defines a comment to be "--", followed by anything, followed by *two* newlines.

Your input only contains one newline after the comment, so you get an error telling you that the parser expected a second newline instead of the `#`.

Comment: then I run into this problem : https://gist.github.com/RoelofWobben/79058b1a6a5c24f08a495045c7a685f9

Comment: The problem is that a line can have a newline at the end or a comment and a newline  or it's the end of the file.

Comment: I made a github repo here : https://github.com/RoelofWobben/logParser  with a issue.